# Code coverage and number of unit test are not showing in sonarQube

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage, .net-6.0, sonarscanner

I am using sonarQube to analyze my code that in .net6.
I've installed sonarScanner and run these 3 commands:

```
dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"<sonar-project-key>"
    /d:sonar.login="<sonar-token>"
    /d:sonar.cs.dotcover.reportsPaths=dotCover.Output.html
dotnet build –no-incremental
dotnet dotcover test --dcReportType=HTML
dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="<sonar-token>"
```

I wrote a lot of unit tests using nunit however the number of unit tests is 0

[image: 1]

I tried to add /d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths="Nunit\Result.xml" but nothing happened

Can you please help to reveal the missing configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that using [Coverlet](https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet) and exporting to OpenCover format.

Make sure these packages are added to your xunit test project:

```
coverlet.collector
coverlet.msbuild
```

To scan:

```
dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover  /p:CoverletOutput="../../" --logger:"trx;LogFileName=..\..\..\TestResult.trx"

dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"test" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000"  /d:sonar.token="XXX" /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths="coverage.opencover.xml" /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=TestResult.trx

dotnet build

dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.token="XXX"
```

Note: in this example the unit tests is located on "\tests\Project.Tests\Project.Tests.csproj", so the output will be placed on "\". This is also the path where the scanner is run.

[image]